# Sweep a for loop output object for duplicates at/near the same time as the output is created

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, duplicates

I have a large data frame(df2) consisting of various species with a lot of different types of data associated with each (~4000 rows/species). I have a for loop that already sweeps through and subsets df2 into individual smaller data frames by species by indexing df2 against a discrete table of the species(df1). The code for that is:

```
for(i in 1:length(df1$x1))
{
assign(paste0("", df1$x1[i]), 
     df2[df2$x1 == df1$x1[i],])
}
```

What I want to do is add a component to/modify the existing for loop above that will sweep each of these smaller output data frames (df*) for duplicate values via a specific column. (If that makes sense...)

Here is an example data frame to work on

```
Date <- (sample(seq.Date(from=(as.Date("2000/01/01")), to=(as.Date("2001/01/01")), by="day", format="%m/%d/%Y"), 25, replace = TRUE))
Alphabet <- (sample(LETTERS[1:26],25, replace = FALSE))
Species <- sample(paste0("Species_", c(1:10)), 25, replace = TRUE)
Numbers <- (sample(1:50,25, replace = TRUE))

df2 <- data.frame("x1" = (Species),
      "x2" = (Alphabet),
      "x3" = (Numbers),
      "x4" = (Date))
```

Here is the example species table needed for the for loop as well:

```
df1 <- data.frame(unique(Species))
names(df1)[names(df1) == "unique.Species."] <- "x1"
```

Thank you for the help, and sorry about any redundant or inefficient code (still pretty new to R)

**Addendums:

1. For the purposes of this example, lets say we are looking for duplicates in the "Date" column of the sample data frame above.
2. Effectively, the desired output would be one data frame which is all the data associated with each species (which the for loop already does) and a sister data frame that is a vector object of any duplicate values found in that output data frame, and should no values be found, the vector would have "NULL" as the values or "0". Ex: for species 1, there would be an output for all data associated with it from the original data, and say there are 3 duplicate dates in species 1, a vector would be made titled "species_1_duplicates" and would contain those 3 duplicate values.`

```
    #Example desired output code`
    Species_1  #The main/original output from the for loop
    Species_1_duplicates <- vector(NULL) #New output if no duplicates were found
    Species_1_duplicates <- vector("01/01/2000", "02/13/2000", "08/08/2000",...) # if these three dates have duplicates in "Species_1"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `sweep each of these smaller output data frames (df*) for duplicate values via a specific column.` ? Which "specific column" ? Can you show how your output would look like?

Comment: Isn't this just `split(df2, match(df2$x1, df1$x1))`?

Comment: ```split(df2, match(df2$x1, df1$x1))``` does work similar to the for loop, but it doesn't create separate output objects for each species automatically unless I am missing something